# Spring returns xml body when request header Accept is wildcard */*

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

After adding spring-security module to my Spring app, when I use postman to post a request with Authorization option is No Auth and header **Accept is */***, the Spring app returns a xml body like:

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>1563355321349</timestamp>
    <status>401</status>
    <error>Unauthorized</error>
    <message>Unauthorized</message>
    <path>/odm/test</path>
</Map>
```

It returns xml when Unauthorize but when the request is successfully authenticated, the body is in json.

I want the Unauthorize response body to be in json instead of xml. I tried to remove MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter from HttpMessageConverters list and it works but I want to keep it in list of course. 
Does Spring prioritize xml over json when Accept header is */* ?

Anyway to set Gson as default http message converter instead of Jackson in Spring boot 2.0 ?

Comment: I added GsonHttpMessageConverter to the first of the list but when I debug into the code, it still use ```AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter``` instead of Gson. I config to use only one  GsonHttpMessageConverter in the list but it still return xml

Comment: You mean the mime type of HttpMessageConverter ? It is GsonHttpMessageConverter so it only support json.